Install multiple instances of windows service via MSI (or other installer)
I was developing an application that eventually was going to be configured as a windows service. Several instances of this application can be run on a single server. So right now we just create several folders with the application binaries and manually configure dedicated windows services. The task that I was given now is to create an installer that would help us to do exactly this thing. We used to use MSI (Wix) for other applications but there were no requirements to set up multiple instances.
Here're requirements to the installer:

Multiple instances of the same app can be installed on the same server
Installed instances should be updatable with the next version via the installer
Installer is free (preferably)

There's another idea that I don't know how to bring to life (if it's possible at all). Instead of performing multiple installations I could allow to select number of instances of the application to install. This would require some dynamic logic baked into the installer. I was thinking of features but they are pretty much static and honestly speaking I can't see how single app can be copied to their own folders with some minor tweaks to configuration file for each of them.
Did someone accomplished similar task in the past? Looking for any ideas and/or suggestions on tools.
I read up on the multiple product installations via MSI and came to conclusion that it might be very tricky to do it as we'll need to deal with transforms and product code which somehow needs to be changed in runtime for every single installation. It's not ideal.

The WiX Toolset has features, such as the Instance element, to help you create such packages. However, do know that multi-instance MSI packages are a very advanced topic. You will want to dig in deep or get help from experts on your journey.

Thanks Rob. I was reviewing possibilities of using instance transforms as it seems the only option to install multiple instances. The idea is to allow a user to do this without any need of fiddling around with command line. That basically leads me to necessity of writing my own bootstrapper which would do the trick. I really want to avoid diving so deep though.
